# How does Murph know whether Dr. Brand is alive?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

In *Interstellar* the data transmission was only one way, that is, from The Earth to the spaceship, and not the other way, then how does Murph know that Dr. Brand is alive?

Comment: But they did send messages back through, how else would the people on Earth know that the three planets (Dr. Mann's and Dr. Edmonds and the other one) were supposedly habitable? Remember, Dr. Mann sent back *false* data showing his planet *was* habitable. Dr. Brand could also have sent back messages.

Comment: Inter related http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27041/how-did-murph-know-about-edmunds

Answer (score 4):

First of all, as explained in the answers to [this related question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/27456/49), **the data transmission isn't entirely one way.** Remember, that they in fact [got the signals from the first exploration missions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27337/49) (the 12 people visiting their respective planets 10 years ago) sent through the wormhole. For whatever reason those signals are rather simple, but they definitely got them, because they are the reason [why they chose to visit those 3 planets only](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27237/49).

And given the fact, that [due to the various time dilations](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27257/49) at this point *Amelia Brand* had [*more or less* just arrived](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27683/49) at *Edmunds*' planet, she likely **sent a new signal out from the planet**. The humans at *Cooper Station* in turn received that signal, knowing that *Amelia* had arrived and the planet is Ok as a new home. The only problem that stands is how *Amelia* was able to send anything else than *"rudimentary, simple binary 'pings' on an annual basis"*. But maybe she did really only get through that much and the humans on our side of the wormhole just assumed it was a sign that she was there.

An entirely different possibility (suggested by *Hypnosifl* in a comment to his [related answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/27630/49)) is that they **sent a probe through the wormhole to check for news** and come right back (since the relay on the other end of the wormhole got and recorded every signal from the planets just fine). Afterall they were sitting in a space station near the wormhole and sending a probe through should be their smallest problem.